# Adding licensing protection to an MFC application

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, licensing

Can anyone advise on the best way to go about implementing copy protection for an application via license-key or whatever.

Are there any standard APIs out there? Or is it standard practise to write your own? 
If so, are there any tutorials out there that demonstrate how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my personal experience I must say, that there is no situation where licensing/copy protection is reasonable.
Either you have a small scale (private) project, that isn't very widespread and therefore not subject to being cracked.
Or you have a large, renown project. In that case, it's going to get cracked anyway, regardless on how much time and money you put into your copy protection.

In my opinion - just save your time and money. If your software is worth being pirated, it will be. But from time to time, there might be someone who pirated your software but says to himself: "Well, this is a fine piece of software and the author doesn't harass me with annoying licensing...I'll pay for it".

Just my 2 cents

Comment: That's a very good option at the minute. Cheers.

Comment: No technical answer, not helpful and untrue. Lots of midsize companies have a strong need for license protection.

Answer (score 3):

A typical way to do this is to compute a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) from a secret key (something only you know) and the user's email -- basically a hash of the two pieces combined. The registration key is the hash. Check out Windows' [Crypto API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379863.aspx) for something that can do HMAC.

There are more complicated ways that some people do licensing, but there's really not a point to it. Always remember: licensing is like a lock on your home doors. It can be broken if someone wants to. It's there to keep people honest, not to keep people out, so don't waste your time going overboard.